# @font-face src:local not working on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-face

This code does not work with Chrome, Chromium, Opera and other Blinks Browsers, but work with Firefox

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SomeName';
    src: local('URW Gothic L'), url('something.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

But.. this one work perfectly

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SomeName';
    src: url('something.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Does Blink support local font?
How can I try to load local font firstly?

Comment: Is this on a live server or are you working 'locally'?